# Is it possible to display the Traefik IngressRoutes in the Kubernetes Dashboard?

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-dashboard

I'm using Traefik as IngressRoute.

With `kubectl api-resources` it is defined as:

```
NAME                              SHORTNAMES                                      APIVERSION                             NAMESPACED   KIND
...

ingressroutes                                                                     traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1           true         IngressRoute

...
```

My problem is that in Kubernetes Dashboard only ingress resources can be viewed, therefore ingressroute resources is not displayed.

How to implement the ability to see ingressroute resources instead of ingresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes Dashboard does not have the ability to display Traefik IngressRoute, the same way it shows Ingress, without changing it's source code.

If you want, you can create feature request in [dashboard GitHub repo](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/labels/kind%2Ffeature), and follow [Improve resource support #5232](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/5232) issue. Maybe in the future such feature will be added.

In the meantime, you can use Traefik's own [dashboard](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/operations/dashboard/).